# Xamarin.forms iOS simulator not launching

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have connected my windows laptop to Macbook pro late 2011 for developing xamarin.forms ios applications. My visual studio version on Widows machine is `16.7.2` with xamarin.ios version `13.20.2.2`.
My xamarin.ios version on Macbook is `13.14.1.39` and Xcode version is  `11.3.1(11C504)`. The problem I am facing is I cannot run ios simulator on both windows and mac. I can manually open simulator on Mac. But when we run application against simulator it will build successful , but no simulator shows up. The simulator drop downs on both visual studio and Xcode shows plenty of simulators with ios 13.3. What should be the problem? I have checked and unchecked `"Remote simulator to windows"` and no change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the version of IDE (Xcode and VS) are up to date .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Hi, The problem my macbook pro is late 2011 and inorder to update to latest Xcode I need to update the os to catelina. Which is not available

Comment: I know this might sound as a surprise (insert surprised Pikachu face here), but you should really consider getting a machine that can actually run a recent stable version of macOS and xcode and VS for Mac. Otherwise, you will run into weird issues which have been solved in newer versions of the tools and probably have no chance of back porting those fixes. If you are serious about developing iOS Apps, upgrade.

Comment: @Cheesebaron  Yes bro.. Need to change.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Actually I doubt that is a problem. My teammate had the same problem, with iMac that couldn't run legitimately latest MacOS (they solved these issues with unofficial patches, without help). So, without any hope with that old Mac I brought my private MacBooc Pro 12, Mid-2012 that legitimately runs Catalina and latest XCode, reconfigured his VS to use my MacBook and yet, exactly the same issue persists. App successfully builds, but the simulator doesn't show up on neither Windows nor Apple machine. 
As a partial solution to the issue, one of teammates found downgrading VS helped.

Comment: I have the same issue too, today updated to 16.7.3 and still not starting.

Comment: @SametSığırcı Oh bro. Then it might be a bug .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It surely is not a problem with Mac. Also, it's not happening with all projects, when I freshly installed latest VS (as of yesterday) I successfully created and ran blank Xamarin.Forms project, yet when I tried running project my mates are working on it still doesn't launch. Now we're trying to figure out how to reproduce this issue so we can properly report a bug with reproducible case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had an exact same problem. In my case, it helped to:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on iOS project -> Properties -> iOS Bundle Signing
2. For Debug | iPhoneSimulator configuration, change Bundle Signing scheme to the "Automatic Provisioning"
3. Click Save All button in Visual Studio
4. Right click on iOS project and select "Unload project"
5. Select unloaded iOS project to see *.csproj file contents
6. In `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">` Remove tags `<CodesignKey>` and `<CodesignProvision>`
7. Click Save all button
8. Right click on iOS project -> Reload Project

Now it should be working.

Comment: Hell yeah !! Worked like a charm bro..Thank you so much..

Comment: Real hero, I have struggled more than a 2 week by this issue. Solved now.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue now, and unfortunately this suggestion did not solve it for me. :(

Comment: absolute legend, still very weird because couple days back I could run the simulator while manual provisioning was on. But now the simulator didn't want to start up while giving no errors. Removing the keys from the debug propertygroup worked to start the simulator back up again! Thanks again man

Comment: Thanks bro. I am trying to fix few hours this.

Answer (score 1):

In my company guys working on Xamarin have the same issue. I can safely say it's not a problem with your old version of MacOS neither of Xcode.
We've got old iMac, which first showed the same problem, so today I brought my private MacBook, all legitimately updated to latest versions of software, but with no luck, same problem.

The solution we've got right now so you can continue development is to uninstall your current version of VS and install previous one, most likely 16.6. This worked for one of teammates, tomorrow we will try fresh install of 16.7, maybe it's issue with VS update system.

Here is link to official MS thing on how to install previous version of VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

I hope this works, I am not 100% sure if that's what my friend was using.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Bro how can we downgrade the VS in windows? Currently we can download only latest version. Isn't it?

Comment: @Anand I added link to MS docs about older version install to my reply. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok bro. Let me try

Comment: @Anand: there's no need for it now ;) See my friend's answer above, we've found the fault ;) btw, don't forget to mark his answer as correct if it helps you, he's new to SO, he'll love the reputation ;)

Comment: Thanks bro...above answer worked.. Many thanks for you and your friend...+1