# error while starting demo application in xamarin.forms (ios)

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, i have a mac paired to my Visual Studio 2019 and when i try to launch the defaut application (which is there when you've just created a project) after starting the simulator it gives me an error [the russian part says "failed to install *** to ***"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7oEb.png) I tried reinstalling xcode and VS on Mac, but it didn't help. I also didn't find anything in google that was similar to this one and I absolutely have no clue what could cause this error, I'm desperate.

Comment: can you launch the app from the home screen?

Comment: no, the iphone simulator just starts loading (shows nothing but the apple logo) and then gives the error

Comment: if the simulator cannot boot that has nothing to do with your app

Comment: Try to launch the simulator on mac first, and then deploy your app from windows vs.

Comment: Can you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809029/9733566

Comment: My bet would be you haven't set your app signing credentials: developer certificate and appropriate profile.

Comment: @VentusFortis Hi, whether you can start it with a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your exact issue; but is it related to this [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1320089/remoted-ios-simulator-shows-up-as-black-screen.html?inRegister=true)?

Try launching your application directly on the Mac to see if that works: Tools>Options>Xamarin>iOS Settings> uncheck "Remote simulator to windows"

Comment: i tried this, the simulator launched on mac but then VS gave me this error and it stopped:

Error  error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.companyname.App4' on the device 'iOS 14.4 (18D46) - iPhone SE (2nd generation)': The request to open "com.companyname.App4" failed.  
  
it seems like it's the same one