# Blazor Hybrid - iOS debug - Microsft.CSharp.dll not signed

Tags: c#, ios, maui-blazor

I'm building an app on Blazor MAUI.

Android works fine (Debug and release).
I pushed the code on my local mac device for debugging. Same Visual Studio version.
When working on iOS, I face an issue where the "debug" mode to my iPAD seems to return a "Failed to Codesign" error.

Here's the errors:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7089/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
/Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app/Microsoft.CSharp.dll (AppName)
```

Below another error which seems to be linked to the Failed to codesign

```
Failed To codesign 
/Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app/Microsoft.CSharp.dll (AppName)
```

The app seems to build on MacOS (have a crash due to incompatibility of packages, but that's not what I'm afraid of).
It just doesn't want to build on my local iOS Device.
When I try to build using the iossimulator it has the same error.

Here's my property group for ios:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CodesignProvision>Codesign Provision</CodesignProvision>
      <CodesignKey>CodeSign Key (FAKEKEY32)</CodesignKey>
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I tried :

- Removing the false
- Adding some extra arguments under the 
  -${ProjectDir} hasn't changed anything
  -Most of the others ${} options basically crash the whole thing with a new error message

  - Adding the `/Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app/` change the problem to System.Web.dll (which is under AppName.app as well)
  - Adding the actual `/Users/userName/Documents/GitHub/doc/AppName/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/AppName.app/Microsoft.CSharp.dll` returns an errSecInternalComponent due to `unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer xxxx`
  - I tried to create a new set of credentials to sign & changed from general App Development to IOS development

I saw [this subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194706/why-is-microsoft-csharp-dll-not-signed-using-vs-ma) but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: 1. You can check if the device is in Devices list at https://developer.apple.com/. And you could try to check if this iPad is included in the profile. 2. In your windows PC, can you try to [Pair to Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac), use [Automatic Mac provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac#automatic-mac-provisioning), then choose [iOS Remote Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/remote-simulator) to see if it works?

Comment: My device was registered at developer.apple.com, but still didn't work when launching from my mac. Then, I followed your links and faced an issue where the simulator would just not launch so I follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775200/xamarin-forms-ios-simulator-not-launching#:~:text=In%20my%20case%2C%20it%20helped,All%20button%20in%20Visual%20Studio) and it launched the simulator on my windows, but it was erroring exit 22 and Xamarin wouldn't install the app. But not ticking "Remote Simulator to Windows" now launches the simulator on my mac but no app is installed.

Comment: Edit:
I delete all the cache of Xamarin in AppData>Local>Xamarin & restarted the connection with my mac.
Now I get the error 22, the same as the one I get when I launch the remote simulator on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for my problem.

Deleting everything and made sure that all reference to any resource was mentioned once (even with the  tag).

I had, for example, some resources mentioned twice in the .csproj file : Once on the `Resources\Images\*` and once as a standalone like `Resources\Images\MyImage.png` (That was a rest of something I was playing with when starting the app).

Now it's working fine.

Found the solution looking at : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15144

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already fixed this issue. In my case the problem were two folders. First of all the Properties folder which contained CultureRecources in my case and a folder which contained .png Pictures and dome additional .dll files. After I removed them everything was working fine. Currently I search for a way to use at least everything in the properties folder. When I find a solution I will add it to this post.